# How to register tg app_globals on a worker thread?

Tags: pylons, turbogears2

I have a turbogears app that makes extensive use of app_globals.

It uses common code that does "from tg import app_globals" and then uses the object.

Until now, this common code was only called in the context of an incoming request.

however, I now want to start worker threads in the app to do processing, and these worker threads needs to call the common code.

How do I register the same "tg.app_globals" on the worker thread?

I am trying to avoid rewriting all my common code to pass around an "app_globals" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TurboGears configuration is always available in any thread after it got processed, so unless you need to access the app_globlas before the configuration process took place you can do that through `tg.config['tg.app_globals']`

Comment: Ok, but my requirements are different. I have commong code, that is using app_globals, for eg, accessing a property using "x = app_globals.foo". I dont want to rewrite all the common code to use tg.config['tg.app_globals'].<property>. Instead, I want to make the worker thread appear as if it was a tg request thread, in other words, I want 'from tg import app_globals; x = app_globals.foo' to work from all threads that I create

Comment: The whole TG context is per request, so tg.request tg.response tg.app_globals and so on are only accessible during a request.

The only exception to this is tg.config which is always accessible, so currently the only way to access the app_globals outside a request is to use tg.config.